# split string according to words between square parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I want to split string using regex.

for ex.

```
val = "[python] how to [css]"
val = "[python][css] how to"
val = "how to [python][css]"
```

my string looks like this(there is try to display different way for value string), and I want to split like:

```
a=['python','css'] #(type list)
b="how to" #(type string)
```

I tried this

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'(\w+\s*)') 
re.findall(pat,val)
```

output:

```
['python', 'how ', 'to ', 'css']
```

What am I doing wrong with my regex?

Comment: Try this regex `\[.*?\]`

Comment: @MarounMaroun no its not work it return only [] value, like `['[python]', '[css]']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x="[python] how to [css]"
print re.findall(r"(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])",x)   # this is the list you want
print re.sub(r"\[[^\]]*\]","",x)             # this is the string you want
```

Try this way.You can have list as well as string.

Comment: you have solution if i have `x="[python] how to [css] when"` then list is at is but string return in another list, like `["how to",
"when"]`

Comment: @i'mPosSible try `x="[python] how to [css] when"`
`print re.findall(r"\[[^\]]*\]|([^\[\]]*)",x)`

Comment: hmm :) not me, Solution is given by @vks

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
import re

val = "[python] how to [css]"
m = re.findall(r'\[(\w*)\]', val)
print m
# ['python', 'css']
```

`\[(\w*)\]` will match all words inside the square bracket

Answer (score 1):

Got first part from question `a=['python','css'] #(type list)`

```
>>> import re
>>> val = "[python] how to [css]"
>>> [i[1:-1] for i in re.findall("(\[[^\]]*\])", val)]
['python', 'css']
>>> val = "[python][css] how to"
>>> [i[1:-1] for i in re.findall("(\[[^\]]*\])", val)]
['python', 'css']
>>> val = "how to [python][css]"
>>> [i[1:-1] for i in re.findall("(\[[^\]]*\])", val)]
['python', 'css']
```

second part:(updated according vks solution)

```
>>> re.sub(r"\[[^\]]*\]","",val) 
'how to '
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex `(\w+\s*)` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]` followed by 0 or more spaces, so it'll match `css` and `python` in `[python]` and `[css]`. This regex: `(\w+\s+)` matches what you want.

You can do the following:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'\[(.*)\]') 
re.findall(pat,val)  # wil return ['python', 'css']
```

Now you can get the rest from an opposite regex (matches everything that's not between `[` and `]`).